# Python 2.7 AttributeError

Tags: amazon-web-services, pagination, boto3, amazon-route53

I keep getting an attribute error and can't figure out what I am missing, using Python 2.7. Any ideas are appreciated, thanks!

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '**self**' error and cannot figure out why?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3
r53 = boto3.client('route53')

def paginate(method, **kwargs):
client = method.__self__
paginator = client.get_paginator(method.__name__)
for page in paginator.paginate(**kwargs).result_key_iters():
    for result in page:
        yield result

for key in
paginate(r53.list_resource_record_sets(HostedZoneId='/hostedzone/XXXXXXXXXXX')):
    print(key)
```

Update: Including Stack Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", 
line 1591, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", 
line 1018, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/juan/Desktop/route53/route53dev.py", line 12, in <module>
    for key in
  paginate(r53.list_resource_record_sets(HostedZoneId='/hostedzone/X')):
  File "/Users/juan/Desktop/route53/route53dev.py", line 6, in paginate
    client = method.__self__
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__self__'
```

Comment: Could you paste the full stack trace for this error, including file names and line numbers? That would help us be able to track down the source of the error.

Comment: Updated with stack trace

Comment: Hm. If you type `dir(dict())` in a python shell, you can see all the attributes of a `dict`, and `__self__` is not one of them. An `AttributeError` is what you get when you try to access an attribute that doesn't exist. What do you expect this `__self__` attribute to do?

Comment: Code snippet I found on a related reddit thread, I don't know what exactly to expect it to do. 
  
 https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/7p5rhl/using_boto3_think_pagination_adam_johnsons_blog/

Comment: Just trying to get the snippet to work, not expecting anything from __self__